# Netbeans 7.4 tasklist

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

The tasklist just disappeared from my netbeans after I downloaded netbeans 7.4. Can someone tell me how to get it back?

Thanks in advance

P.S I am using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Window->Action Items from main menu